# How to create a new dataframe from old dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with lots of measurements of temperature values. I want to count the number of measurements in every day of the month. So far, I managed to display the number of measurements, and also to create a new dataframe, containing the unique values of the days. 
How can I add the number of measurements to the new dataframe(the one containing all the unique values of days), in a new column?

So far, I have managed this function, which counts the number of measurements in the given day:

```
def measurements_in_a_day(day, month, year):
    full_date = day.format(), '/', month.format(), '/', year.format()
    full_date = ''.join(full_date)
    seriesObj = data.apply(lambda x: True if x['day'] == (full_date) else False, axis=1)
    no_of_rows = len(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
    print('Number of Rows in dataframe in which date is ', full_date, ' are ', no_of_rows)
```

The thing is that I have to call this function 3 different times, because the csv file doesn't save the save format for data. How can I add the count of measurements in a new column in the dataframe created for unique month days?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data.

Comment: Could you add the input data and expected output data?

Comment: @iulianaiuliana what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1=df.groupby('day')['time'].count().reset_index()
df1=df1.rename(columns={'time':'count'})
```

In one line:

```
df1=df.groupby('day')['time'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'time':'count'})
```

If you prefer having the days as index you can do the following

```
df1=df.groupby('day')['time'].count().rename('count')
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using pandas groupby ?

something like data.groupby('day').count() should give you what you want.